# .Net MAUI Blazor - Variable does not save the actual value after re-rendering

Tags: razor, blazor, components, rendering, maui

So I'm trying to set class change for navigation items, but Blazor re-renders the ActiveContext variable, so it's always the first one in the end. Is it possible to disable the re-initialization of the ActiveContext after the component was re-rendered?

Here the code of the component:

```
<footer class="bottom-bar-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="bottom-bar flex-row">
            <div class="nav-item px-1"></div>
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class=@($"bottom-bar-nav-link {ActiveContext[0]}") @onclick="() => SwitchNavBarActiveClass(0)" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                    <div class="icon-wrapper">
                        <img src="img/main-icon.svg"/>
                    </div>
                    <span>Головна</span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class=@($"bottom-bar-nav-link {ActiveContext[1]}") @onclick="() => SwitchNavBarActiveClass(1)" href="counter">
                    <img src="img/home-icon.svg" />
                    <span>Компанії</span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class=@($"bottom-bar-nav-link {ActiveContext[2]}") @onclick="() => SwitchNavBarActiveClass(2)" href="fetchdata">
                    <img src="img/qr-icon.svg" />
                    <span>QR</span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class=@($"bottom-bar-nav-link {ActiveContext[3]}") @onclick="() => SwitchNavBarActiveClass(3)" href="testapi">
                    <img src="img/map-icon.svg" />
                    <span>Карта</span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class=@($"bottom-bar-nav-link {ActiveContext[4]}") @onclick="() => SwitchNavBarActiveClass(4)" href="testapi">
                    <img src="img/user-icon.svg" />
                    <span>Профіль</span>
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item px-1"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</footer>

@code {
    private string[] ActiveContext = { "selected", "", "", "", "" };

    private void SwitchNavBarActiveClass(int itemIndex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ActiveContext.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == itemIndex)
            {
                ActiveContext[i] = "selected";
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveContext[i] = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I expect to have memorized ActiveContext after re-rendering to have the actual nav item with "selected" class

Comment: Declare it as a static variable or create a static variable to store it.

Comment: yep, I did that as a service

Comment: You may also try using [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=windows) to store and retrieve the value.